# Inconsistent sizing of empty table cells with Safari vs. Chrome

Tags: html, css, google-chrome, safari

Given the following snippet of HTML + CSS:

```css
table {
  border-collapse: collapse;
  border: 1px solid black;
}

td {
  border: 0;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
</head>
<body>
  <table>
    <tr>
      <td><div>1</div></td>
      <td></td>
      <td></td>
      <td></td>
      <td></td>
      <td></td>
      <td></td>
      <td></td>
      <td></td>
      <td></td>
      <td></td>
      <td></td>
      <td></td>
      <td></td>
      <td></td>
      <td></td>
      <td></td>
      <td><div>1</div></td>
    </tr>
  </table>
</body>
</html>
```

I see different positioning of the table elements in Chrome vs. Safari.

Chrome:
[image: Chrome Table]

Safari:
[image: Safari Table]

It seems as though the empty table cells take up size within the table with Safari, but not with Chrome. What's perhaps more surprising is that, with Safari, the presence of empty cells in this table is affecting the size of the final, right-most cell containing content. (You can verify this by toggling `display: none;` on the empty table cells, or simply deleting them -- you should see this affect the table layout with Safari, but not with Chrome).

My over-arching questions, then:

1. Why is Safari rendering empty table cells this way?
2. Is there some magic CSS incantation that will ensure Safari doesn't give these empty table cells any sizing?

For what it's worth, this issue appears to be unique to having `padding: 0;` applied to the table cells.

For reference, the above screenshots were taken with Safari 10.1 (12603.1.30.0.34), and Chrome 58.0.3029.110.

Comment: Just curious. You posted an answer to your question, but then you deleted it. Did it turn out not to work? (I don 't have Safari here, so I can't check myself.)

Comment: It fixed the layout issue seen in the last content-containing cell, but unfortunately the inner empty cells are still rendered with a width of 1px. (As far as I can see, with `padding: 0;`, WebKit will render empty table cells with a width of 1px, whereas other browsers will render them with 0 width)